# Get one everytime I iterate through a data table

Tags: .net, vb.net, for-loop, datatable

Here's my current code:

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    For Each item In markerDtable.Rows
        If keyData = Keys.Space Then
            comboSearchMarker.Text = item("MarkerName") ' Gets the items in MarkerName field but I need only one at a time.
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

If you run this code, it gives all the names in the `MarkerName` field. Anyway, how can I get *only one* as I press `SpaceKey` then the next one if I press it again? Sorry, I don't really have an idea.

Comment: That code makes no sense. In your loop you are not even evaluating the `item` - so whats the purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you iterate over all the items using the `For Each` loop. That's why you get all the entries if `SPACE` is pressed. I guess your problem is how to remember which entry you returned last time :-)

You need to declare a static variable that remembers the last index:

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    Static lastEntryReturned As Integer = 0
    If keyData = Keys.Space Then
        comboSearchMarker.Text = markerDTable.Rows(lastEntryReturned).Item("MarkerName")

        lastEntryReturned += 1
        If lastEntryReturned >= markerDTable.Rows.Count
            lastEntryReturned = 0
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

This "remembers" the last index returned until the function is called next time. The need for a "global" variable outside this function is removed as the local variable is `static`. It is thus valid also between calls to the function.

Comment: Sorry, copy & paste strikes again :-) Fixed.

Comment: it skips an item. For me its okay, but I thought of, what if my `row.count` is an even number, then it wouldn't get the odd ones?

Comment: I'm going to edit my answer to avoid this. The problem is that I put the code to increment `lastEntryReturned` outside the code that handles the space key. So the variable is incremented no matter which key you press.

Answer (score 0):

Declare variable for position outside of this function.

```
Dim pos As Integer
```

Then in function:

```
If (keyData = Keys.Space and pos < markerDtable.Rows.Count) Then
    pos += 1
    comboSearchMarker.Text = markerDtable.Rows(pos).Item("MarkerName")
End If
```